# how to create and save the playlist

Tags: c#, winforms, axwindowsmediaplayer

i am trying to develop a media player using windows media player component in c#.net. this is my code by which i can make play list and add the songs to the playlist and the name of the playlist will be shown in the listbox named "playlistviewbar" and then i have set this playlist to current playlist.

but when i run the project and current plaulist set it ask to play the media that is not match wich player. it shows that it has extension "." and it fails to play the media

can any one help me to resolve this problem and also help me for saving the playlist..

```
WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist pl;
 public WMPLib.IWMPMedia files1,paths1;
 string playListName;

    private void toolStripButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listnametxt.Text == "")
        {
            playListName = "Untitled playlist";
        }
        else
        {
            playListName = listnametxt.Text;
        }
        pl = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playlistCollection.newPlaylist(playListName);
        playlistviewbar.Items.Add(playListName);

    }

    private void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string[] filestring=openFileDialog2.SafeFileNames;
             string[] pathstring=openFileDialog2.FileNames;
            for (int i = 0; i < filestring.Length; i++)
            {
            files1 = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(filestring[i]);
            paths1 = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(pathstring[i]);
            pl.appendItem(paths1);
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist =pl;
            }


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

here is the code which is working for me :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var pl = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("plList");
            pl.appendItem(axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(@"D:\nosazi.wmv"));
            pl.appendItem(axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(@"D:\tasadof.mp4"));

            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist = pl;
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();            
        }
```

Comment: While using this solution, I found out that the next item in the playlist plays for 2 seconds before the previous ends. It then again plays second one from the beginning. Is there a way in which I can delay the playing of next item in the playlist by 2-3 seconds?

Comment: actually I know there is some thing called crossfading, if you could find a way to do that settings for your object i think it's do the trick. using the player it's self you can even set the time overlap ...